# DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection doesn't close the connection

Tags: jdbctemplate

I have a situation. I am using JdbcTemplate to update a table with blob fieds. i ask for a connection using DataSourceUtils.getConnection method. Here everything is ok. I can update the table without problems. But when i try to release the connection using DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection method, this doesn't close the connection and never release it. So my ConnectionPool crash after a while. I am using springframework 3.2.6. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you found the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same issue resolved here but seems like `conn.close()` has to be called in the finally.

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/43182-datasourceutils-hanging